# Cómo puedo multiplicar estos valores

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

Me da error de #valor, pero he probado con la opción TEXTO Y CON LA OPCIÓN VALOR y nada de nada no se puede

Yo no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, seguro que luego es lo más tonto que parió padre, pero ahora mismo, estoy tan tan tan tan bloqueado que no consigo hacer que funcione

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula que intento poner es =MULTIPLY(B35;='Precios $ Crypotomonedas'!A292) pero en la hoja donde está ='Precios $ Crypotomonedas'!A292 dicho valor es un número en este caso concreto sería 3,24.

Entonces si yo cojo el valor de la 2ª hoja de cálculo llamada (Precios $ Crypotomonedas) y busco el valor de la celda A292 (3,24), cuando dicho valor lo llevo a la hoja de claculo 1 y pongo sus valores me da =MULTIPLY(B35;='Precios $ Crypotomonedas'!A292) #VALOR diciendo (En la función MULTIPLY, el parámetro 2 espera número valores, pero '$3.24' es texto y no puede ser forzado a número.)

Comment: ¿Podrías ponerlo como texto? Una imagen hace más difícil ver tu problema, sin mencionar los que estén en un dispositivo con pantalla chica o tengan problemas de vista. Además, sería bueno que describas qué estás intentando multiplicar.

Comment: Bienvenido Alberto. He puesto una respuesta parcial que es lo que te podría decir con los datos que proporcionas. Si requires algo más específico [edit] tu pregunta para agregar la descripción del mensaje de error y los valores que estás intentando multiplicar. Cabe mencionar que en preguntas del tipo "por qué este código / fórmula no funciona" es recomendable incluir un [mcve], que en este caso sería poner los valores a multiplicar y la fórmula en celdas contiguas.

Answer (score -1):

En las hojas de cálculo de Google además de mostrarse un mensaje de error como valor a mostrar en la celda como el de #VALUE, al pasar el puntero del mouse sobre el triángulo rojo se muestra una descripción que en algunos casos explica claramente cuál es el error, por ejemplo, indicando el cuál de los parámetros está provocando el error y el motivo. Por ejemplo, en un intento de reproducir el problema obtuve lo siguiente:

> **Error**
>   En la función MULTIPLY, el parámetro 2 espera número valores, pero  'dñjkfñljasdfña' es texto y no puede ser forzado a número